# Can someone help me answer to this question

Tags: multithreading

An application is used to take 1 second to generate one invoice file. A new code is launched 4 threads in parallel and is executed on a dual-core machine.
How much would it take to finish the generation of 100 invoices?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Getting help is what this site is all about.  To make sure you get the most from the site, be sure to ask for help that makes you independent and builds your skills.  "I need the answer to homework problem number six" type questions might get you out of a hard place; but, the answer alone won't help you if you see a similar but different problem in the future, so ask about how to solve these problems, instead of asking for the answers.

Comment: Note that we help you solving problems. We don't do your homework for you. So please turn to the [help] to learn how and what to ask here. And when asking for help with homework, then always include your own efforts.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on hardware with Hyperthreading 1 core would support 2 threads. So you will have a total of 4 threads supported by your cpu. Probably the answer will be aproximaty 25(even with hyperthreading it does not run exactly 2 times faster).

Without hyperthreading 50

Comment: So if 1 core supports 2 threads, a dual-core can support 4 threads.Which means that if
1 invoice file is generated in 1 second, with 4 threads running on parallel, on a dual-core cpu, 100 invoice files are generated in 100 seconds,  as long as the number of threads in every invoice file, doesn't exceed 4, on the dual-core cpu.

Comment: Not exactly. 1 thread is aways generating 1 invoice for 1 second. 4 threads if hyperthreading is supported will generate 4 invoices for 1 second. For 100 seconds 400 invoices.

Comment: What I am saying is that the thread is running per invoice it is not running 4 threads doing the same invoice. It. is 4 threads 1 invoice per thread.

Comment: And keeo in mind. It depends on the hardware, almost every desktop and laptop pc supports hyperthreading, but not all. And then you have 2 cpu threads available instead of 4.

Comment: ok, I got it! Thank you very much sir, I appreciate it!

Comment: Keep in mind, with hypertreading or not, that one thread cannot advance on two cores at the same time.  So a 1 threaded soltion won't run in 1/2 the time on two cores.

Answer (score 0):

To run, a program or thread must be "on" a core.  On means that core is actively processing the instructions of that program or thread.

So, a program that launches with 4 threads on a 2 core machine can only see two of its threads advanced (being run) at any point in time.  This means you can't run all 4 threads at the same time.

This should be enough for you to figure out the timing, because you've been told that one thread (or program) can craete one invoice in one second if it runs on one core (threads and processes can jump from core to core; but, they cannot run on two cores at the same time)

Comment: Naaahh.... I am not sure about that, I core should support 2 threads.

Comment: This would be 4 logical cpus.

Comment: Hyperthreading is this called

Comment: You're state this as if any CPU core only supports one thread in hardware. Which is simply wrong.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Not all CPUs support hyperthreading, and this is not a real world issue, it's a homework problem.

Comment: We pretend it is :)

Comment: @GhostCat Reputation brings out the worst of us :D

Comment: @GhostCat In Linux, a core is either a physical processing unit, or the additional hyper-thread of a physical processing unit, which is an additional set of memory that utilizes the same processing channel as the primary processing unit.  The performance of hyperthreads is slightly less than the performance of the true core; because, the hyperthread waits for the processing pipeline in the core to be available (when the actual core isn't using it).  Trust me, 30+ years, and now doing cluster computing.  These performance items matter in my field.

Comment: @GhostCat Some of us, even with our decades of experience, remember what it is to be a student, and the pressures of not having the support team around us when we need direction in a field that might not be shared by a group of friends.  That's why I answer very poorly written questions.  These people don't even know about upvoting, so it's not about the reputation, it's about giving back for those that gave to me.

Comment: @EdwinBuck thumbs up from me.